# How to Fill data in Spinner using Webservice?

Tags: java, android, web-services

Following is my code - I have a simple spinner to show array data. I am getting the array by calling a WebService. The array fills up properly but the app crashes when spinner is called.

I tried to call the AsyncTask in my main activity and declare my array outside the onCreate activity but the array gets initialized automatically.

Please help -

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    private String[] loan_type = new String[5];
    String[] curr_arr = new String[5];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Call Web-Service to fill the drop down list

        loan_type = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loan_type);
        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();

        //*******************************************



    }


    //Create Async Task
    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String[]... params) {
                        //Invoke webservice
             String[] temp_arr = new String[5];
             Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
             temp_arr = CallWebService.invokeHelloWorldWS("Hello","getCurrency");

             if (temp_arr[0] != null){
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, temp_arr);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //Set response
            //tv.setText(displayText);
                        //Make ProgressBar invisible
            //pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
                        //Make ProgressBar invisible
            //pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }

    }
    //**************************************************************************
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here' the working code -

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    private String[] loan_type = new String[5];
    String[] curr_arr = new String[5];
    String[] temp_arr = new String[5];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Call Web-Service to fill the drop down list

        loan_type = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loan_type);
        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();

        //*******************************************



    }


    //Create Async Task
    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String[]... params) {
                        //Invoke webservice


             temp_arr = CallWebService.invokeHelloWorldWS("Hello","getCurrency");


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //Set response
            //tv.setText(displayText);
                        //Make ProgressBar invisible
            //pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (temp_arr[0] != null){
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, temp_arr);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
                        //Make ProgressBar invisible
            //pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }

    }
    //**************************************************************************
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Yup please post your LogCat. Will be easier for us to help you with it.

Comment: You are not allowed to call UI Elements from another Thread than the main thread. Move your UI updates to the onPostExecute method in your AsyncTask.

Comment: Hi, here is the Link for log file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byc3_Zu5NDPKT1kyZ3QtamFqRkE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

```
doInBackground
```

is an asynchronous method from where you may not change the UI. You violite that rule by setting up the `Spinner`. 
Pass any data that you retrieved in doInBackground to the `onPostExecute`, which runs on the UI thread, and create your spinner there. 
If your app crashes, have a look at the stacktrace which most of the time tells you what's wrong. Also post the stacktrace if you ask a question :)

Comment: Thanks. Updated the code. I did try that as well but I guess I was declaring the spinner in my Main Activity and that was the reason why it was failing. Declared the array outside the methods, declared the Spinner inside onPostExecute and also wrote the UI code in onPostExecute and it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You must do your view operations on `onPostExecute` in your task.

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        //Invoke webservice
        String[] temp_arr = new String[5];
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        temp_arr = CallWebService.invokeHelloWorldWS("Hello","getCurrency");
        return temp_arr ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] temp_arr) {
        if (temp_arr[0] != null){
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, temp_arr);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
                    //Make ProgressBar invisible
        //pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

}
```

Comment: protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params)  is not allowed

Comment: So you can return into the older codes and define a public String[] object

Comment: But the only mistake u have done is doing your spinner operations on onDoingBackground. Take them into onPostExecute

Comment: return temp_arr ; is not allowed. Just return null as null is of type Void